# fancy about $f(x+a)=f(x)$ , where $a$ is any non-real complex number

Tags: functional-equations

It is well-known that when $a$ is any non-zero real number, the most general solution of $f(x+a)=f(x)$ should be $f(x)=\Theta(x)$, where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with period $|a|$ .

Now when $a$ is a non-real complex number, what is the most general solution of $f(x+a)=f(x)$ ? I don't believe that $f(x)=c$ only, where $c$ is any complex number.

Comment: It is $f(x)=\Theta(x)$, where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with period $a$.  This says nothing, like the statement in the question about the real case.  A nonconstant example is $\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi x}{a}\right)$.

Comment: A nice example is the complex exponential function $e^z$.  Here, $a=2\pi i$ is the non-real period.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
S=\{x+\lambda a:x\in\mathbb{R},\lambda\in[0,1)\}
$$
and define $f$ on $S$ any way you want. Then $f$ can be uniquely extended to $\mathbb{C}$.

On the other hand given $f$ satisfying $f(x+a)=f(x)$ you easily see that values of $f$ uniquely determined by values of $f$ on set $S$.